# SonarCFamily plugin for SonarQube Community Edition

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I've tried to add the SonarCFamily plugin for SonarQube Community Edition (v 7.0) 
i know that Community Edition is the only free version and it suppports only 9 languages but does not support a plugin for c++ projects 
i've tried to add cppcheck plugin and it's working fine.

Any idea if it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SonarCFamily simply won't work for you without a commercial license. It is not a free analyzer.